# delegation of authentication fails when opening web application from another network

Tags: asp.net, web-services, networking, kerberos-delegation

I've been developing a web application calling an authenticated web service located on another server through the use of delegation of authentication and Kerberos.  Everything is working fine when the user authenticates through a browser/desktop located on the same network as the server (Intranet context).  When the desktop is on another network than the servers (ex: from Internet), I get prompted for credentials, which is expected.   After that the web services server returns "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." message.  This happens even if I add my web application to the "intranet" or "trusted site" Security Zone in Internet Options, in Internet Explorer (11).  I also tried with Chrome but same result. I don't understand what creates that error. I expected the behaviors to be the same on both networks. Maybe someone has an idea for the cause of that behavior?

Attached is a diagram to help clarify the context.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason it cannot work is that the connection falls back to NTLM instead of using Kerberos. Therefore, delegation of authentication is not possible.